# Limit different number of workers for different groups of celery tasks

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task

For different celery job groups, how can we limit the number of workers asynchronously differently.

Here is a good reference on how to group different celery tasks together : https://sayari3.com/articles/18-chains-groups-and-chords-in-celery/

**I need to do this dynamically in script are there any ways to do this?** For example, I want to limit 10 parallel workers for job1 and 5 parallel workers for job2 in following script.

```
#tasks.py
from celery import group
@app.task
def task1(param):
   # ...
@app.task
def task2(param):
   # ...

job1 = group([task1.s(param) for param in params])
job2 = group([task2.s(param) for param in params])

job1.apply_async() # limit 10 workers 
job2.apply_async() # limit 5 workers
```